# My document root is not working in WampServer so CSS and header/footer not visible unless I take absolute links out

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, wampserver

I am building a site and viewing it live on Wamp Server.

I have changed the document root in httpd.con and despite the document root being  c:/wamp/www/mysite/html in my http.con file, it will not show any php, css or images which I would have thought would work.

This is the error message I get:

Warning: include(C:/wamp/www//includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\mysite\html\index.php on line 5

If I change line 5 in index.php to

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."mysite/html/includes/header.php");
```

instead of

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/header.php");
```

then I can see the header, just with no css, no images either.

**Note:** I have tried with and without the / and no luck unless I add "mysite/html/" in the document_root php as above, then I can see the header! But with no CSS unless I take the / out of the link (taking absolute links out).

Also, everything (images, css etc) works if I just take the / away from the start of them. For example changing 
    
 to 
     makes the images appear.

And the same with the css file links and other image links, and links to other pages.

Basically, I have to take the absolute links out for them to work, but then that will work on the site root and not when I go to a sub-directory.

**Troubleshooting**

To find out if my document root was working I made a new php page called info.php with the following code in it

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

then went to http://localhost/info.php and I got a 404 error.

So I went to http://localhost/flying-squid/html/info.php

and the info was displayed.

It says

```
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] C:/wamp/www/
```

even though in httpd.con it says

```
ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9"
```

Are these meant to be the same?

Also, under Apache Enviroment it says

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT  C:/wamp/www/
```

where as in my httpd.con file it says

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite/html/"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

So basically my documentroot is not working, and it not pointing to the right folder, hence I am having to add the folder names into the code which surely I shouldn't have to?

Any advice much appreciated. I am very new to all of this so perhaps I am doing something wrong. Do I not have permission to change these? But I haven't changed the server root and this is still wrong so surely not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case it helps anyone in the future, had to go to

C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and change the entry for localhost to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite/html"

ServerName localhost 

</VirtualHost>
```

And now it all works and my document root points to the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another server running on the same machine, check the access logs for this installation and make sure your visits are showing.

Comment: What do you mean another server? And how do I check the access logs? I did have to delete and re-install wampserver as I had skype on whilst installing so it didn't install properly, uninstalled it all though..